# Cannot install http-builder in grails

Tags: grails, httpbuilder

I have a strange behaviour in my grails 2.3.6 app.

I'd like to use groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder but IDE reports that it's unable to resolve the class.

So, I added the following line to my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
build "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7"
```

But I get the following exception:

```
$ grails run-app MyApp
| Configuring classpath
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:zip:0.7 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Could not find artifact org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:zip:0.7 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

My repositories in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
mavenRepo "http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository"
mavenRepo "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/"
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
```

The strange thing is that it should be there: http://repo.grails.org/grails/webapp/search/artifact/?1&q=http-builder

Any thoughts? I cleaned up, deleted ~/.m2, ~/.groovy, ~/.grails

Thanks!

Comment: Weird. It's working for me. I'm using `runtime('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1')` as a dependency.

Comment: others downloaded, so it's no proxy?  is this via maven or ivy?

Comment: 0.7 worked here.  have you put it in `plugins` instead of `dependencies`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the scope of your dependency, it should be `compile` rather than `build`. In other words, replace this

```
build "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7"
```

with

```
compile "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7"
```

If you're still having problems, cross-reference your `BuildConfig.groovy` with [this one](https://github.com/domurtag/festivals/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy), which correctly declares a dependency on this library.

Comment: Thank you @Donal! I had the referencies in "plugins" instead of in "dependencies". However the IDE continues to mark the HttpBuilder in red as "unable to resolve" but the run-app goes through.

Comment: @elkarel I guess you're using Eclipse? It's support for Grails is not very reliable IMO and it frequently reports bogus errors like this

Comment: Yeah, that IDE is based on Eclipse and its apparently project policy :-/ Thanks!